# Is accessing elements on a 16 byte aligned contigous memory with paddings between elements faster than tightly packed elements in memory?

Tags: c++, memory

So imagine if we had a custom memory allocator that we initialize with a size of 64, and whenever we want to construct a new element inside it, the allocator aligns every element's starting address to be a 16-byte aligned address.

**For example:** If the allocator allocated a memory on heap that starts from address `0x00 to 0x40`, and when we allocate four 32-bit integers inside it, the memory addresses of them would be: `0x00, 0x10, 0x20 and 0x30`.

Now let's imagine another custom allocator that also allocates a 16-byte aligned memory. For example if we say the size to be 15, the allocated memory address will range from `0x00 to 0x10`.

But this time, instead of aligning each element's starting address to be a 16-byte aligned memory, this allocator will put the elements next to each other.

**For the sake of our argument,** let's again assume that we are trying to construct four 32-bit integers inside this allocator's buffer. This time, the starting addresses of these integers will be `0x00, 0x04, 0x08 and 0x0c`.

My question is; which of these allocators will result in less CPU instructions, (sorry if am wrong with this, because it may result in same instructions) or will yield faster read times on a 64-bit system?

Comment: It depends, benchmark your particular use case and see what happens. Code, compiler and CPU will all affect the answer

Comment: I will do, but just wanted a view on which one would result faster read times

Comment: "Faster read times" depends *greatly* on your memory access patterns and cache coherency.

Comment: The threshold, which matters (feasability aside) would be the size of the cache line on your system. If you stay below that, I would expect both to be equally fast. The next threshold is the size and usage pattern of your first level cache. Fechting and replacing cache lines incurs cost you would want to minimize.

Comment: Hmm, so there is no direct, easy or certain answer to this. Let's also assume we iterate them from start to end contigously. Would that still depend on other factors apart from CPU cache sizes? I am assuming the second one which holds them tightly would result in higher read speeds, because of not exceeding the cache lines?

Comment: @guacamoleku: "*Let's also assume we iterate them from start to end contigously.*" Why did you allocate them discontiguously if you're going to access them contiguously? Please stop trying to out-think the language. Also, C++ won't let you do that, because those 12 bytes of padding don't constitute an array.

Comment: You’re putting the cart before the horse. The only way to know which is faster is to do both And measure.

Comment: malloc() on x86_64 already returns 16 byte aligned blobs for speedy SSE operations. So your first case describes the current allocator. Your second case describes the array allocator, simply do new `uint32_t[100];`. Now both cases will often result in the same opcodes (unless the compiler can use SIMD on the array or double loads). But the discontigious case will use far more memory, utilize only a fraction (25%) of the cache and therefore always be slower. Except when you have threads and false sharing. But then you need 64 byte alignment, not 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A 16-bit Processor

Let's say I have a processor that loves to make fetches of 16-bits.

When data is aligned on a 16-bit boundary, the processor only has to make one fetch:

```
  +---+---+  
4 | a | b |  
  +---+---+
```

In one fetch, the processor can get both `a` and `b` (which are 8-bit quantities).

If we have data that is not on a 16-bit boundary, the processor would have to make two fetches, then do some bit shifting and masking to make a 16-bit word.

```
  +---+---+  
2 |   | a |  
  +---+---+  
4 | b |   |  
  +---+---+
```

In the above example, the 16-bits of data are at memory location 3.  In order to get the quantity `ab`, the processor has to make a fetch at address 2 (to get the `a` quantity), then make a fetch at address 4 to get the `b` value.  This is 2 fetches instead of 1, not to mention the extra effort to get `a` and `b` into one 16-bit word.

The net effect is that your program is slowed down.  Whether the efficiency loss is negligible is another matter.

### A 32-bit Processor

A 32-bit processor is geared up to be most efficient at fetching 32-bit quantities.  So when the processor is told to fetch data that is not on a 32-bit boundary it has to make at least one extra fetch, similar scenario to the 16-bit scenario above.

Some 32-bit processors may be optimized to also perform 8-bit fetches, so to fetch 3 bytes (3 x 8-bits), the processor would make 3 8-bit fetches.  (Although it could be wired to make a 32-bit fetch and then use bit shifting and masking to place the 8-bit quantities into separate registers).

### Memory Alignment and Address Decoding

Let start off with the understanding that there is one address line for every power of 2 in the address range.  When accessing memory the fundamental technique is to convert the address to binary and set the address lines accordingly.

However, routing all these address lines around the PCBA board gets complicated (and costly).  Some platforms may eliminate the first address line for 16-bit alignment and the first and second line for 32-bit alignments (draw the picture and you will see that these lines are not used for the associated fetches).  So, with memory aligned on 32-bit boundaries, accessing items not aligned will need to make multiple fetches from memory because the memory may not have all the address lines decoded.  This will slow down your program.  Whether the slow down is negligible is another matter.

Comment: This actually clarified things a bit more to me. I tried to ask about a subject that I had just gotten in, so I thought at first if I align start every element in memory on a 16-byte aligned address, it would be faster. But it actually depends on how the CPU fetches those memory slices, whether that be a 16, 32, 64, 192 byte fetch. Thanks!